# Redirecting output of shell script to text file

Tags: linux, bash, shell, at-job

I am trying to redirect the output of my script(scheduled using at command) to a text file.

```
at -f shelltest.sh -v 11:33 > data.txt
```

Even the script is running successfully, the output is not getting saved to output text file(data.txt).

Say my script demands to check for the "adb devices" then perform reboot, when i schedule the script using at command, neither the command prompt not displayed or the output of a script is not getting saved in text file.

How to save the output of a script in text file.

**Note:** 

Text file is having read/write permission.

Comment: Did you try: `at -f shelltest.sh -v 11:33 > data.txt 2>&1`?

Comment: It redirects the output of at command(job id info) (job 22 at Fri Nov 7 11:33:00 2014)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The shell is doing precisely what you are requesting: It is running the `at` command, and redirecting its output to the file.  So while you may be hoping (or even expecting) that the output of the `at` job you scheduled would end up there, that is not at all what you are saying.  You are saying, and getting, "please redirect the output of the scheduling operation to this file."

The workaround is kind of cumbersome, but given the above, should hopefully make sense.

```
at -v 11:33 <<'HERE'
shelltest.sh >data.txt
HERE
```

If you have Bash, you can use a here string as well:

```
at -v 11:33 <<<'shelltest.sh >data.txt'
```

Or you can use `echo` or `printf`:

```
printf '%s\n' 'shelltest.sh >data.txt' | at -v 11:33
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
echo 'shelltest.sh > data.txt' | at -v 11:33
```

#### Notes

Consider how the shell interprets this command:

```
at -f shelltest.sh -v 11:33 > data.txt
```

- The shell sees the command `at` with four arguments: `-f`, `shelltest.sh`, `-v`, and `11:33`.  The shell cares not what those arguments mean.  The shell simply passes them on to `at`.
- The shell interprets `> data.txt` to mean that the output of `at` should be sent to `data.txt`.  This redirection has not affect on what happens When `shelltest.sh` is finally run.